# Finding all permutations for a given number of football games in ocaml

Tags: recursion, ocaml, permutation

I have to write the function series : int -> int -> result list list, so the first int for the number of games and the second int for the points to earn.

I already thought about an empirical solution by creating all permutations and filtering the list, but I think this would be in ocaml very dirty solution with many lines of code. And I cant find another way to solve this problem.

The following types are given

```ml
type result = Win (* 3 points *)
| Draw (* 1 point *)
| Loss (* 0 points *)
```

so if i call

```
series 3 4
```

the solution should be:

```
[[Win ;Draw ;Loss]; [Win ;Loss ;Draw]; [Draw ;Win ;Loss];
[Draw ;Loss ;Win]; [Loss ;Win ;Draw]; [Loss ;Draw ;Win]]
```

Maybe someone can give me a hint or a code example how to start.

Answer (score 0):

Consider calls of the form `series n (n / 2)`, and consider cases where all the games were `Draw` or `Loss`. Under these restrictions the number of answers is proportional to `2^n/sqrt(n)`. (Guys online get this from Stirling's approximation.)

This doesn't include any series where anybody wins a game. So the actual result lists will be longer than this in general.

I conclude that the number of possible answers is gigantic, and hence that your actual cases are going to be small.

If your actual cases are small, there might be no problem with using a brute-force approach.

Contrary to your claim, brute-force code is usually quite short and easy to understand.

You can easily write a function to list all possible sequences of length `n` taken from `Win, Lose, Draw`. You can then filter them for the correct sum. Asymptotically this is probably only a little worse than the fastest algorithm, due to the near-exponential behavior described above.

Answer (score 0):

A simple recursive solution would go along this way:

- if there's 0 game to play and 0 point to earn, then there is exactly one (empty) solution
- if there's 0 game to play and 1 or more points to earn, there is no solution.
- otherwise, `p` points must be earned in `g` games: any solution for `p` points in `g-1` game can be extended to a solution by adding a `Loss` in front of it. If `p>=1`, you can similarly add a `Draw` to any solution for `p-1` in `g-1` games, and if `p>=3`, there might also be possibilities starting with a `Win`.